# python natsort sort strings recursively

Tags: python, sorting, natsort

I find that with [`natsort.natsorted`](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/intro.html#quick-description) the sorting order changes part-way through a string:

```
In [31]: import natsort as ns
In [32]: ns.natsorted(["01-08", "02-07", "01-06", "02-09"])
Out[32]: ['01-08', '01-06', '02-09', '02-07']
```

In this case, the behaviour I want is:

```
In [33]: sorted(["01-08", "02-07", "01-06", "02-09"])
Out[33]: ['01-06', '01-08', '02-07', '02-09']
```

Comment: @SethMMorton, is there something I'm missing in the documentation?

Comment: ``ns.versorted`` seems to have the behaviour I'm looking for, but I wish to use it on paths, and other strings, not versions. Is that recommended use?

Comment: Yes, you can use `versorted` with `ns.PATH` without any issue at all.

Comment: Or, as mentioned in the accepted answer, you can use `ns.INT | ns.UNSIGNED | ns.PATH`, or `ns.I | ns.U | ns.P`.

Comment: You no longer need to deal with the shenanigans of modifying the algorithm when using `natsort` anymore for all but special cases.  Simply using `ns.natsorted(["01-08", "02-07", "01-06", "02-09"])` works as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ns.natsorted(["01-08", "02-07", "01-06", "02-09"], alg=ns.ns.INT | ns.ns.UNSIGNED)
```

The problem is that natsorted is interpreting your strings incorrectly. This manually sets the algorithm to look for unsigned ints. Otherwise, it searches for signed ints, and that "-" causes problems (if you interpret "-08", for example, as -8, then the sorting makes sense).

This is actually equivalent to versorted, which is just a shortcut for this algorithm, but I think it's better to explicitly write what you're doing, especially as versorted could change to be more applicable to versions in the future.

Comment: of course! I completely forgot it was being interpreted as a negative sign. thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that in `natsort` version >= 4.0.0 (in the near future), the default behavior will change to `ns.INT | ns.UNSIGNED` to better meet the "least astonishment" principle, so this should work right out of the box then.

Comment: You no longer need to deal with the shenanigans of modifying the algorithm when using `natsort` anymore for all but special cases.  Simply using `ns.natsorted(["01-08", "02-07", "01-06", "02-09"])` works as expected now.